# Get value and type of python variable similar to Jupyter behavior

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Assume you have a Jupyter notebook with one entry that has three lines:

```
x = 1
y = x + 1
y
```

The output will print '2'

I want to do this inside my python code. If I have a variable `lines` and run exec:

```
 lines = """x = 1
            y = x + 1
            y"""

 exec(lines,globals(),locals())
```

I will not get any result, because `exec` returns None. Is there a way to obtain the value and type of the expression in the last line, inside a python program?

Comment: Add a statement "print y"?

Comment: no, I can't alter the code

Comment: what if you add a `print(y)` after the `exec`?

Comment: no, because I don't know the name of the variable that needs to be printed, all I know is that is the expression in the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `exec` add a `print()` of the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) of the last line **to get the value**, like so:

```py
lines = """x = 1
y = x + 1
y"""

exec(lines,globals(),locals())
print(eval(lines.split("\n")[-1]))
```

Then to add in the `type()`, you add in running the type on that `eval()` to then **get the value and type** shown:

```py
lines = """x = 1
y = x + 1
y"""

exec(lines,globals(),locals())
print(eval(lines.split('\n')[-1]),"          type: {}".format(type(eval(lines.split('\n')[-1])))) # I put the
# last line code into string format with `.format()` because f-string didn't like the `\n`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51775950/8508004
```

---

Be cautious when using `exec()` and `eval()`. See paragraph starting 'Keep in mind that use of exec()..' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694087/8508004) and links therein.