# Python f-string: replacing newline/linebreak

Tags: python, python-3.7, f-string

First off all, sorry: I'm quite certain this might be a "duplicate" but I didn't succeed finding the right solution.

I simply want to replace all linebreaks within my sql-code for logging it to one line, but Python's f-string doesn't support backslashes, so:

```
# Works fine (but is useless ;))
self.logger.debug(f"Executing: {sql.replace( 'C','XXX')}")

# Results in SyntaxError: 
# f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
self.logger.debug(f"Executing: {sql.replace( '\n',' ')}")
```

Of course there are several ways to accomplish that *before* the f-string, but I'd really like to keep my "log the line"-code in one line and without additional helper variables.

(Besides I think it's a quite stupid behavior: Either you can execute code within the curly brackets or you cant't...not "you can, but only without backslashes"...)

This one isn't a desired solution because of additional variables:

[How to use newline '\n' in f-string to format output in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780357/how-to-use-newline-n-in-f-string-to-format-output-in-python-3-6)

*General Update*
The suggestion in mkrieger1s comment:

```
        self.logger.debug("Executing %s", sql.replace('\n',' '))
```

Works fine for me, but as it doesn't use f-strings at all (beeing that itself good or bad ;)), I think I can leave this question open.

Comment: You don’t need an f-string here. Just use `logger.debug("Executing %s", sql.replace(...))` for the additional benefit of not doing the string interpolation when it's actually logged.

Comment: @mkrieger1 #1) Your suggestions works fine for me, thank you! Until now I just really preferred f-strings #2) The Question/Answers you found didn't, I read that one before...

Comment: This comment solves your problem without helper variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780357/how-to-use-newline-n-in-f-string-to-format-output-in-python-3-6#comment76542691_44780357

Comment: @Sanyash: It uses an additional variable for the newline...so it works, but it is not the solution i want :)

Comment: It doesn't use additional variable. It uses `chr(10)` without declaring a variable on separate line. Do you feel the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found possible solutions

```
from os import linesep

print(f'{string_with_multiple_lines.replace(linesep, " ")}')
```

Best,

Comment: Thank you, used that in the meantime already, seems to be the most correct (and plattform independant) way for me,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
newline = '\n'
self.logger.debug(f"Executing: {sql.replace( newline,' ')}")
```

Comment: They specifically noted "without additional helper variables."

Comment: exactly, don't want to use an additional variable for the newline, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ok, maybe not exactly what @evilive asked for, but an elegant solution for something very close!

Answer (score -1):

1. don't use f-strings, especially for logging
2. assign the newline to a constant and use that, which you apparently don't want to
3. use an other version of expressing a newline, `chr(10)` for instance

> (Besides I think it's a quite stupid behavior: Either you can execute code within the curly brackets or you cant't...not "you can, but only without backslashes"...)

Feel free to take a shot at fixing it, I'm pretty sure this restriction was not added because the PEP authors and feature developers wanted it to be a pain in the ass.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use "f strings" (formatted strings) when logging? And why do you need to assign `\n` as a constant? there's no speed improvement or readability improvement?

Comment: Same reason why you wouldn't use % or .format for logging: because that makes the formatting eager and means the logging-processing pipeline can't work on the various items, which it may want to.

Comment: Could you explain #1 (don't use it) a little?

Comment: Use use one of the previous methods of formatting strings: logging has its own (based on printf patterns), just `logging.debug(format_string, *args)` and it'll do the formatting internally, alternatively outside of logging contexts use % or .format.

Comment: @evilive see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148790/lazy-logger-message-string-evaluation

Comment: @Masklinn Not sure I follow, and this might be because I've never stumbled upon the problem. But `.format()` would only in-line replace `{var}` for `var` before sending it to the logger. in this case, `sql` will be in-line injected and then passed to the logger. The logger can then work on the expanded string, where's the issue? Passing `*args` to the formatter would be equal to `f'{sql}'` in this case?

Comment: That it can only work on the string post-formatting, meaning you can't build up on the pre-formatting string (e.g. to classify logging messages or deduplicate when sending messages across the network) because logging never sees it. And if logging is disabled, it also incurs the formatting costs which would otherwise be skipped, and which can sometimes be significant.

Comment: @Torxed re: assign newline to constant - because that circumvents not being able to use a backslash in an f-string.