# Python - drill down to a new line - List in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm exercising dictionaries therefore I have the following

```
favorite_place = {
    'ppl1': {
        'person': 'josh',
        'places': ['Central park', 'Hollywood', 'Aspan']
    },
    'ppl2': {
        'person': 'mark',
        'places': ['Ands mountain', 'Himalaya mountain', 'Dead sea']
    },
    'ppl3': {
        'person': 'yossi',
        'places': ['times square', 'Osaka', ',McDonald\'s']
    },

}

for budy, places_info in favorite_place.items():
    ID = f"{budy}"
    PERSON_NAME = f"{places_info['person']}"
    PLACES = f"{places_info['places']}"
    print(f"\nPerson Identified by: {ID}\n"f"For {PERSON_NAME.title()}")
    print(f"The favorite places are:\n"f"\t",str(PLACES).strip('[]').replace('\'', ''))
```

output:

```
..................... ..................
Person Identified by: ppl3
For Yossi
The favorite places are:
     times square, Osaka, ", McDonald's"
```

How do I take this, for example:

```
 times square, Osaka, McDonalds
```

and make it to be like this -separated by a new line and with out the a comma??? :

```
times square
Osaka
McDonalds
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Please repeat your materials on string processing and available methods.
Also, please remove the inapplicable code from your posting: you ask only about changing the appearance of strings -- the dict portions don't seem to be part of your question at all.

Comment: pls see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780357/how-to-use-newline-n-in-f-string-to-format-output-in-python-3-6

Comment: `PLACES = '\n'.join(places_info['places'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use newline '\n' in f-string to format output in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780357/how-to-use-newline-n-in-f-string-to-format-output-in-python-3-6)

Comment: not that much, 
But somehow managed to pull this off

Answer (score 0):

```
favorite_place = {
    'ppl1': {
        'person': 'josh',
        'places': ['Central park', 'Hollywood', 'Aspan']
    },
    'ppl2': {
        'person': 'mark',
        'places': ['Ands mountain', 'Himalaya mountain', 'Dead sea']
    },
    'ppl3': {
        'person': 'yossi',
        'places': ['times square', 'Osaka', ',McDonald\'s']
    },

}

for budy, places_info in favorite_place.items():
    ID = budy
    PERSON_NAME = places_info['person']
    PLACES = places_info['places']
    print(f"\nPerson Identified by: {ID}\nFor {PERSON_NAME.title()}")
    print(f"The favorite places are:\n", '\n '.join([i for i in PLACES]))
```