# How to avoid creating a newline when using if-else in f-string expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Please see the below minimal example,

```
printbbb = True
print(f"""AAA
{'''BBB''' if printbbb else ''}
CCC""")
```

This prints

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

as desired, however, if I set `printbbb` to `False`, it prints

```
AAA

CCC
```

How can I change the code so that it will print

```
AAA
CCC
```

when `printbbb` is set to `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list to improve readability:

```py
printbbb = True

to_print = ["AAA"]
if printbbb:
    to_print.append("BBB")
to_print.append("CCC")
print("\n".join(to_print))
```

Or you could conditionally add a newline character:

```py
nl = "\n"
printbbb = True
print(f"""AAA{nl + "BBB" if printbbb else ""}
CCC""")
```

Another variation by [Swifty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20267366/swifty):

```
nl = "\n"
printbbb = True
print(f"""AAA{f"{nl}BBB" * printbbb}
CCC""")
```

Maybe even use three `print` statements:

```py
printbbb = True
print("AAA")
if printbbb:
    print("BBB")
print("CCC")
```

Comment: I wonder why python wouldn't allow us to simply write the more readable `print(f"""AAA{"\nBBB" if printbbb else ""}`. Otherwise, I think your second solution will work for my situation.

Comment: @user3667089 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780357/how-can-i-use-newline-n-in-an-f-string-to-format-output

Comment: This works though: `nl='\n' ; print(f"""AAA{f"{nl}BBB" if printbbb else ""}""")`, and this too: `nl='\n'; print(f"""AAA{f"{nl}BBB" * printbbb}""")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to replace the space.

```
printbbb = False
print(f"""AAA
{'BBB' if printbbb else ''}
CCC""".replace('\n\n', '\n'))
```

Comment: This works for the minimal example, but in the actual use case, the f-string is large, and it contains valid `\n\n` outside of the if-else that shouldn't be replaced to `\n`