# Add a new line in list in python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to add a new line to a list in python like we do it in strings using \n in the 'print' function itself.

```
print("40: ",dataset[40], "400: ",dataset[400])
```

the output of the above is :

```
40:  ['Rachel', '97'] 400:  ['Janet', '18']
```

but I want the out be :

```
40:  ['Rachel', '97']
400:  ['Janet', '18']
```

How do I do this in python in the 'print' function itself please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use newline '\n' in an f-string to format output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780357/how-can-i-use-newline-n-in-an-f-string-to-format-output)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using f string...

```
print(f"40: {dataset[40]}\n400: {dataset[400]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the python `format` method and the new-line character `\n` to format the resulting print.

Example code:

```py
# Generating data for demo
dataset = {40:['Rachel', '97'], 400:['Janet', '18']}

# Printing the result
print("40: {}\n400: {}".format(dataset[40], dataset[400]))
```

Resulting print:

```
40: ['Rachel', '97']
400: ['Janet', '18']
```

The '{}' fields inside the string are used to indicate where to parse the value when calling the `format`.