# Script not writing to file

Tags: python

I would like to make it so that it opens up alan.txt, search the text for all instance of scholary_tehologian and if found, add the word "test" under it. when I tried doing it this way:

```
## Script
with open('alan.txt', 'r+') as f:
for line in f:
    if "scholarly_theologian" in line:
        f.write("test")
```

it wouldn't write anything. I'm in Windows 8.1

Comment: That will just overwrite the next four characters with "test".

Comment: the file does have a line with "scholarly_theologian", I tested it.

Comment: Ok, so what I put "\ntest"? Creates a new line with the word test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I modify a text file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: If you wrote "\ntest" you would overwrite the next *five* characters.  You cannot "insert" into a text file, you can only append.

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten answer because the last one was wrong.

If you want to read lines you have to put **.readlines()** after **open(...)** or **f**. Then there's a few ways you could insert "test".

```
 ## Script
with open('alan.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if "scholarly_theologian" in lines[i]:
         lines[i] = lines[i] + "\ntest"

with open('alan.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: the phrase I'm looking for is scholarly_theologian", even when I do this, it still doesn't work but thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Completely re-written the answer now.

Comment: Use `xrange(len(lines))` instead of `range(lines)`

Comment: I meant before the one-liner edit. Now it's wrong again, it should be `"\n".join(lines)` like it was before

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a file like this. You can only append to it, write characters instead of others, or rewrite it entirely. See [How do I modify a text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python).

What you should do is create another file with the content you want.

**EDIT:**

Claudio's answer has the code for what I offered. It has the benefit (over manicphase's code) of not keeping the whole file in memory. This is important if the file is long. manicphase's answer, on the other hand, has the benefit of not creating a second file. It rewrites the original one. Choose the one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    with open('alan.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            o.write(line)
            if line.find('scholarly_theoligian'):
                o.write('test')
```

Like [Ella Shar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332509/ella-shar) mentioned, you need to create a new file and add the new content into it.

If working with two files is not acceptable, the next step would be to delete the input file, and to rename the output file.