# how we can take value from website by using python code?

Tags: python

```
import urllib
from datetime import date,timedelta
import datetime
import re
list =["infy.ns","grasim.ns","idea.ns","asianpain.ns","bajaj-auto-eq.ns",
       "drreddy.ns","boschltd.ns","kotakbank.ns","M&M.ns","ultracemc.ns",
       "sunpharma.ns","lt.ns","acc.ns","sbin.ns","bhartiartl.ns",
       "lupin.ns","reliance.ns","hdfcbank.ns","zeel.ns","ntpc.ns",
       "icicibank.ns","cipla.ns","tcs.ns","bpcl.ns","heromotoc.ns"]
i=0
while i<len(list):
    url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+list[i]+"&ql=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext=htmlfile.read()
    regex='<span id="yfs_l84_'+list[i]+'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print(price)
    i=i+1
```

i have to take value from finance.yahoo.com 
when i run that code by using terminal then i got all value on terminal but i want to put that value in my desktop text file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify a text file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way requires no coding. Simply redirect the script's output onto a file, e.g.

```
python yahoo_scraper.py > prices.txt
```

or

```
python yahoo_scraper.py >> prices.txt
```

to append to an existing file.

Doing it in Python is also easy. Open a file for writing and write to it:

```
with open('prices.txt', 'w') as price_file:
    i=0
    while i<len(list):
        url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+list[i]+"&ql=1"
        htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
        htmltext=htmlfile.read()
        regex='<span id="yfs_l84_'+list[i]+'">(.+?)</span>'
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
        print(price, file=price_file)
        i=i+1
```

Be aware that this will overwrite the file each time the script is run. If you want to *append* to the end of the file, open it in append mode by replacing `'w'` with `'a'`.

Your while loop would be better written as a for loop. Here is an example - I have assumed that `list` is renamed to `stocks` to avoid shadowing the builtin `list`:

```
stocks = ["infy.ns","grasim.ns",....]

with open('prices.txt', 'w') as price_file:
    for stock in stocks:
        url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}&q1=1".format(stock)
        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        pattern = r'<span id="yfs_l84_{}>(.+?)</span>'.format(stock)
        price = re.findall(pattern, html)
        print(price, file=price_file)
```

You might need to change the last line to print the first element of the list returned by `re.findall()`.

Comment: i got that error when i compile with that what is the solution for print(price, file=price_file)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax