# Insert comma into text file using Python

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to add a comma into my `.txt` file using Python.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    fileText = f.read()

filedata = fileText.split('\n')
```

The above code would read the file and split it by newline.

Text file is something like this:

```
ABC  name1, name2, name3

XYZ  nameA, [nameBa nameBb], nameC
```

I need to add a comma after the first string only. The file contains 4 or 5 strings; most of them are separated by comma except the first one.

I have used two `for` loops to work out the same, but I am thinking it would be better if I could write into my text file using Python and insert only the comma then I will only have to use one loop to get all of the strings.

Expected result:

```
ABC, name1, name2, name3

XYZ, nameA, [nameBa nameBb], nameC
```

I am using `list` structure but `dict` might be better as I can use the first string as key (`ABC`, `XYZ`) and store the rest in either values or as a list made up of all the other strings.

Can anyone help me with inserting the comma into my text file at a specific location (i.e. fourth character from the left on every line)?

Comment: You have a list of strings in `filedata` right? Why don't you loop through this list and `split()` each string by a ` ` character, then the first item of the corresponding list will be `["ABC", "name1", ..]` and then `join()` the required items using `,`

Comment: Thanks.  Split() each string by a separator doesn't give me same result i.e. ["ABC", "name1", ..] instead I get ABC  name1, name2..

Answer (score 1):

You can build such a `dict` like this:

```
d = {}
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.split(' ', 1)
        d[k.strip()] = [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Using above code, I get dict key with first string and second i.e. {'ABC\tname1,': [name2 name3] etc. etc.  I have coded in few more lines using simple for loop such that first string(ABC) as dictionary key and I have split records for each line but I only managed to do it with first two stings as they are separated by \t and rest of stings by commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file, 'r+') as file
```

the `+r` will append to the line. Check out this question its basically the same: [Python insert characters into txt file without overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444482/python-insert-characters-into-txt-file-without-overwrite)

Comment: I have used r, a, w etc. but i am trying to figure out a way to go into text file exact location i.e. 4th character of each line and then append comma there.  would that be a byte location?

Answer (score 0):

As you said your main goal is :

> I can use the first string as key (ABC, XYZ) and store rest in either
>   values or as a list made up of all the other strings.

You can use regex here , And you can get result without adding comma:

```
import re
pattern=r'(^\w+)\s.(\w.+)'
final_dict={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.finditer(pattern,line)

        for find in match:
            final_dict[find.group(1)]=[find.group(2)]

print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'XYZ': ['nameA, [nameBa nameBb], nameC'], 'ABC': ['name1, name2, name3']}
```

Comment: Thanks.  for some reason I was getting unwanted truncation on values i.e {'XYZ': ['ameA, nameB'], 'ABC' : ['ameD, nameE'] etc. I deleted the first .  from pattern and it shows the full value without truncation. ta

Comment: @naveed if my solution helped you can accept the answer :)