# Removing lines after one selected in file using python

Tags: python, function, file

I have a function that I want to use to delete a set of lines in a file called Schedule.txt. I want it to delete 6 lines in total, with an input at the beginning, asking the user which time to delete, which is the first out of six lines. This is as far as I've got. If anyone can help me to delete the 6 lines, please answer!

```
def delete ():
    train = int(input("Enter the train time that you want to remove: "))
    file = open("Schedule.txt", "r")
    file.read("|  Train: "+train)
```

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I didn't get it. You want to delete what? "A function" (cf. first sentence)? Six code lines? Six  lines in a file? Only some text in a file? How does this file look like? What don't you understand? You should be more precise, we simply won't be able to help you overwise.

Comment: SORRY! I worded it wrong! I want to delete lines in a file using a function!

Comment: @vmmonteco I have reworded the question

Comment: Give us a sample of  the text file and what you want the output to look like because I don't get what you are looking for.

Comment: Result: Remove one of the paragraphs.

Comment: From what I understand, if you type in 1305, you want that whole line deleted?

Comment: (DAMN! When I press enter, it just publishes!) http://pastebin.com/cFfb7jAn to see the text file and example result

Comment: @KevinR. No, I want that whole section removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
import fileinput
import sys

def delete ():

    train = input("Enter the train time that you want to remove: ")
    train = train.strip()

    # REMEMBER WHICH LINE THE TRAIN WAS FOUND ON
    train_found_on = None

    # OPEN THE FILE FOR IN-PLACE WRITING
    for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('schedule.txt', inplace=1)):

        # NEVER WRITE OUT THE LINE WHERE THE TRAIN WAS MATCHED
        if 'Time:' in line and train in line:
            train_found_on = i
            continue

        # NOR THE LINES AFTER IN THAT BLOCK
        if train_found_on and i < (train_found_on + 7):
            continue

        # BUT WRITE OUT THE OTHERS
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

See also this post: [How do I modify a text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python)