# Find a string in a file and replace the whole line

Tags: python, linux, scripting

I am Recently quite new to python and am trying to write a script.
What would be the easiest way to search for a string in a file and replace the whole line. I have found that re.sub can achieve this, but nothing is specific enough that I can do it.

For example:

```
    #configuration file
    Stuff that configures a file
```

to

```
    #configuration file
    Port 22
```

by searching for configures

Also does this command have different functions such as searching for a string 
 in the middle of a line and replacing everything after it.

Comment: Please show us your attempt :)

Comment: also, this might help you get started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` to replace the port number.

```
with open('resume.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    upd_port = file_data.replace('22', '4832')
with open('resume.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(upd_port)
```