# What is the most simple way to remove a row in a CSV using Python CSV?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I'm having trouble finding clear and concise methods of removing a select row from a CSV using the CSV module (not the Panda since it's required to be installed). I would also like to remove a range of rows separately. Every article and every question I've seen either or abroad are not clear at all and tend to include specific logic people are asking about. I just want a clear cut answer that is very simple.

I would like to use argv to provide a filename, beginning row number, and end row numbers. So something like python Script.py /CSVfile.csv 1 5, meaning the file name and remove rows 1 through 5 (beginning and ending). I'm new to Python scripting and I get halfway there, but there is always some logic people include that isn't relevant to what I need to do. I just keep getting blocked (as I typically do when trying to code), any help is appreciated.

```
import csv
import sys

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]

with open (var1, 'w') as file1:
   reader = csv.reader(file1)
   for line in reader:
      file1.writer()
```

Comment: Since you can't modify a file inplace while iterating over it, you should create another file and just write the rows you want to it.

Comment: Yes. 
Read original file -> Put it's content into a data structure -> Change elements of that data structure -> Write it to new file or overwrite the original

Comment: You can use fileinput inplace to overwrite the original file with the new file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enumerate the lines and do not copy them if their index is in the range you want to exclude:

```
import csv
import sys

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]

with open (var1, 'r') as file1:
   reader = csv.reader(file1)
   for i, line in enumerate(reader):
      if (i < var2) or (i > var3):
          # process line...
```

If you want to filter the file *in place*, you would write the selected rows to a temporary file and finally rename to new file to the old name, but here there are no valid reason for parsing the rows

```
import sys
import tempfile

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]

(file2, name2) = tmpfile.msktemp()     # get a temporary file
try:
    with open (var1, 'r') as file1:
       for i, line in enumerate(file1):
          if (i < var2) or (i > var3):   # copy selected lines to temp file
              dummy = file2.write(line)
    file2.close()
except:
    remove(name2) # error: remove tempfile
    file2 = None
if file2 is not None:      # successful copy: rename to initial name
    remove(var1)
    rename(name2, var1)
```

Comment: Great, thanks Serge, this helps me get on the right track. :-)

Comment: Doesn't temfile need to be defined?

Comment: Also do I need to import os for remove and rename?

Comment: So I was able to get the first one you put above to a place where it's writing to a secondary file, which is fine, but all it does it writes the entire contents of file1 to file2... I'm stuck. Using 

'writer.writerow(line)' 
after 
'if (i < var2) or (i > var4):' 

I added another variable for the secondary file.

Answer (score 1):

similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

```
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as f:
     old = f.read() # read everything in the file
     f.seek(0) # rewind
     f.write("new line\n" + old) # write the new line before
```

go to line number using seek and add '\n' or whatever.