# How to prepend new rows at the beginning of an existing csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Assume this is my `csv` file: `(df)`

```
id,name,version,ct_id
1,testing,version1,245
2,testing1,version2,246
3,testing2,version3,247
4,testing3,version4,248
5,testing1,version5,249
```

Now I've performed some operation on the file and write it to another `csv` file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('op.csv')

df1 = df.groupby('name').agg({'version': ', '.join, 'ct_id': 'first'}).reset_index()

df1.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Now I've another csv file. `(df_1)`

```
id,name,version,ct_id
36,testing17,version16,338
37,testing18,version17,339
```

I want to write this to my existing `test.csv` file which I created earlier but I want to insert these two rows at the beginning of the file rather than at the end.

I tried something like this.

```
df_1.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', index=False) 
# This does append but at the end.
```

I would appreciate if someone could help?

Comment: Side note: "append" specifically means "to the end of". You want to insert.

Comment: It seems you can't do that. Read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

Comment: @Bazingaa I think that is too specific. You could concat the two sets of data and overwrite the existing file. For all intents and purposes, it's still the same old file but modified

Comment: Append means add at the end. You are asking how to *insert* data at the start of a file. The only way to do that is to move the existing data to make space for the new one. If anything goes wrong while moving the data, you end up with garbage. A *safer* option is to copy the new and old data to a *new* file and replace the original. Another option is to load the dataframe again, add the new lines then write it out over the original file.

Comment: Why do you want to insert the rows anyway? Is there any particular reason, eg there's a lot of data (100s of MBs) which makes loading the CSV expensive?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I'm reading the file in chunks and making modifications and want to prepend those rows at the beginning. I've looked all over S/O couldn't find anything that could help me. So I asked to see if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3):

Prepending A in B is same as appending B to A.
The below code should work for the above case.

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df_1 = pd.read_csv('df_1.csv')

df_1 = df_1.append(test_df, sort=False)
df_1.to_csv('test.csv')
```