# How to select and add entry to a markdown file in Python?

Tags: python, markdown

I have a `data.md` file as follows:

```
## intent:greet
- hey
- hello
- hi
- good morning
- good evening
- hey there

## intent:goodbye
- bye
- goodbye
- see you around
- see you later

## intent:affirm
- yes
- indeed
- of course
- that sounds good
- correct

## intent:deny
- no
- never
- I don't think so
- don't like that
- no way
- not really
```

Now I want to add a new example `yes, I affirm` to `## intent:affirm` so that it becomes as follows:

```
## intent:affirm
- yes
- indeed
- of course
- that sounds good
- correct
- yes, I affirm
```

How to achieve this in Python?

Currently, I have no idea on what to start with as I am new to Python, so haven't done anything concrete before seeking help here other than search online for related articles.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit more difficult than it seems since you can't just edit a file in python (unless it's at the end). So you can first read the file into an array, and then re-write it. For example:

```
# Load the file into file_content
file_content = [ line for line in open('data.md') ]

# Overwrite it
writer = open('data.md','w')

for line in file_content:
    # We search for the correct section
    if line.startswith("##"):
        section = line.strip()

    # Re-write the file at each iteration
    writer.write(line)

    # Once we arrive at the correct position, write the new entry
    if section == "## intent:affirm" and line.strip() == "- correct":
        writer.write("- yes, I affirm\n")

writer.close()
```

Comment: It removes the `\n` at the end of the string, and whitespaces at the beggining and the end of the string

Comment: My bad, it was supposed to be `writer`. I just edited it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rewrite the file, if you can still access, use copy/paste and in the new file insert the copied file and the parts you want to add. You can't change it because it is a os thing, not python. You may be able to replace the file using the terminal or command line in your OS.

Windows:

`REPLACE [Drive:][path]SourceFiles [Drive:][path2] [/A] [/P] [/R] [/W]` where:

`/A` is any missing files

`/P` is prompt for confirmation

`/R` is replace even read-only file

`/W` is wait/pause (originally used for floppy disks)

Linux:

Create and save the new file in the tmp folder, then in the terminal:

`cat /tmp/new-file | sudo tee /home/user/(insert more folders and file if needed)`

OS X/Mac:

I am unsure how to do this as I have never had a mac, but Google or maybe some communities in StackExchange.