# replacing a character in a line of string

Tags: python, replace

I have a .txt file with 20 lines. Each line carrying 10 zeroes separated by comma.

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

I want to replace every fifth 0 with 1 in each line. I tried .replace function but I know there must be some easy way in python

Comment: Is your expected output the corrected input text file, or something else?

Comment: if you know that the file you want needs to contain 20 lines, each containing 4 zeroes, one 1, and 5 zeroes, then why do you need to replace anything?

Comment: I definitely don't have just 20 lines. Its a big file with huge number of lines, each line carrying huge number of zeroes separated by commas.  In each line, I have to replace some zeroes at specific positions with 1. In question I asked for a smaller template, using the answers I can apply the code on a bigger file. @Tim I need the output as the corrected input text file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text string with the below command.

```
text_string="0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
string_list= text_string.split(",")
```

Then you can replace every fifth element in the list `string_list` using insert command.

```
for i in range(4,len(string_list),5):
    string_list.insert(i,"1")
```

After this join the elements of the list using `join` method

```
output = "".join([str(i)+"," for i in string_list])
```

The output for this will be :

```
'0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,'
```

This is one way of doing

Answer (score 0):

If text in this File follows some rule, you can parse it as CSV file, and change every fifth index and rewrite it to a new file.

But if you want to modify the existing text file, like replace the character then you can use seek refer to [How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)