# Why regex is not working to replace the text in place

Tags: python, regex

I have a file and I want to change a particular string in the file. Here is what I am trying

```
import re
with open ('input.txt', 'rw' ) as f:
    content = f.read()
    content_new = re.sub('destination', r'TEST', content, flags = re.M)
```

But this is not actually doing anything or updating the file. i.e I am not seeing the `destination` updated to  `TEST` . Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Is it that I am not writing to file? or ??

Comment: According to the code you are reading from the file, but not writing into it. The code should be: "read -> replace -> write"

Comment: what is in `content`?

Comment: @J'e It contains the object for everything in file i believe

Comment: @loginpassword i don't think that worked exactly, can u help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving your modification. You have read the contents of your file and modified it - But then you are throwing away the modification.

Here's a simple example of you can write it to a different file called output

```
import re
with open ('input.txt', 'rw' ) as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content) # Original content

    content_new = re.sub('destination', r'TEST', content, flags = re.M)
    print(content_new) # Modified content

    f2 = open('output.txt', 'w') # Writing to a different file
    f2.write(content_new)
    f2.close()
```

Also, read the answers to this question - [How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

Comment: I see, But i wanna write to same file

Comment: Yes - That's why I provided a link at the bottom. There are certain associated challenges well explained there

Comment: @KsitiMistishisty To keep the data safe, you need a separate output file. If everything (edit, write, close - see also fsync) has finished without errors, only then is it OK to replace the original file by the output file. Should anything unexpected happen, just remove the output file and start over.