# Python: print and overwrite the same line reading from a file

Tags: python-3.x

I know that this question has been asked before but after a long search I've couldnt find any solution that helps me.
currently, I'm trying to open a file given by a user, read the file content and print each line in the same line overwriting the line.

Expected result:

Trying: xxx --> replace the xxx and write trying: yyy in the same position.

when tyring to implement this option I could get it with numbers but not with strings.
this is my code example:

```
wordlist = input("Enter wordlist path")
with open(wordlist, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as wl:
for line in wl:
    r = requests.get(url + '/' + line)
    sys.stdout.write('trying: %s' % line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Have you try `print(line, end="\r")` , it should work for string.

Comment: yeah I tried it but no success, it prints new line every time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from 2008 addressing the same issue:

[How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

To sum up: you will have to create a new file, open the existing file and write the modifications to the new file. In place modifications are not possible.

Comment: You have to use str(j) in the code below. This will convert the integer to a string

Comment: yeah I've already tried it. still an error