# How to edit a text file at a specific line or location

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing

I have a text file of the format below, and I am trying to edit/update text in the file.

VAR_GROUP
Var1 :  DATATYPE1;(Description Var1)
Var2 :  DATATYPE2;**(Text to be added here)**
Var3 :  DATATYPE3;(Description Var3)
Var4 :  DATATYPE4;**(Text to be added here)**
END_GROUP

Using Python I am trying to add certain description of for eg., Var3 and Var4. With code I  wrote the logic is working fine but the text is added to the end of the file and not at the required position.

```
def search_write_in_file(file_name, string_to_search, description):
with open(file_name, 'r+') as file_obj:
    # Read all lines in the file
    for line in file_obj:
        # For each line, check if line contains the string
        line_number += 1
        if (string_to_search in line) and flag_found == 0:
            line = line[:-1]+description+'\n'
            file_obj.write(line)
            flag_found =1

read_obj.close()
```

**Current Output**
VAR_GROUP
Var1 :  DATATYPE1;(Description Var)
Var2 :  DATATYPE2;
Var3 :  DATATYPE3;(Description Var3)
Var4 :  DATATYPE4;
END_GROUP
Var1 :  DATATYPE1;(Description Var1)
Var2 :  DATATYPE2;(Description Var2)
Var3 :  DATATYPE3;(Description Var3)
Var4 :  DATATYPE4;(Description Var4)

What could be the possible reason that the the mentioned specific location is not edited, rather added at the end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked into the mentioned solution before posting my question. Does that mean there is no possibility to edit a file without copying the file contents into a new file ?

Comment: Yes, you have to do the read/write cycle to modify some part of the file. If you want to avoid copying, you can overwrite the old file with your modified file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use regular expressions to match and replace text inside your file

```
import re

def search_write_in_file(file_name, string_to_search, description):
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as file_obj:
        text = file_obj.read()
    new_text = re.sub(string_to_search,r"\1 {0}\n".format(description),text)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file_obj:
        file_obj.write(new_text)
    print(new_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_write_in_file('text_to_edit.txt',r'(DATATYPE2;\n)',"test2")
    search_write_in_file('text_to_edit.txt',r'(DATATYPE4;\n)',"test4")
```

This will update the existing file to be

```
VAR_GROUP
Var1 : DATATYPE1;(Description Var)
Var2 : DATATYPE2; test2
Var3 : DATATYPE3;(Description Var3)
Var4 : DATATYPE4; test4
END_GROUP
```

Comment: Thanks @scotty3785. This is what I was expecting and it works without rewriting the whole file. But if I wish to iteratively call the function "search_write_in_file" then I need to pass the regex as a variable, and not like r'(DATATYPE2;\n). How can this be achieved ?

Comment: @abhi0687 The function I wrote already supports the regex being passed as a variable. Rather than using the regex directly in the function call, pass it in as a seperate variable. `my_regex = r'(DATATYPE2:\n)'` then `search_write_in_file('text_to_edit.txt', my_regex, 'test2')`

Answer (score 1):

Use the python seek() function. Using this you can change the cursor position in the file character by character.
Also, change the mode to a+ in your function as in r+ mode you can only read the file. In w+ mode, the file would be overwritten.

Read more about it in this website:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_seek.asp

Comment: An example would improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: I added a website link in which you can find more about this and other file methods in python.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Website links are helpful; however, if the site is removed for one reason or another, it is recommended to include an example directly in the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have opened the file in `r+` mode.
Writing to a file needs `w+` or `a+` mode.
Try this:

```
def search_write_in_file(file_name, string_to_search, description):
 lines=[]
 with open(file_name, 'r+') as file_obj:
     # Read all lines in the file
     lines = file_obj.readlines()
 # Make the changes
 for idx in range(len(lines)):
     line = lines[idx]
     # For each line, check if line contains the string
     if (string_to_search in line) and flag_found == 0:
         line = line[:-1]+description+'\n'
         lines[idx]=line
         flag_found =1
 # w+ mode truncates the content and then writes the content back again
 with open(file_name, 'w+') as file_obj:
    file_obj.writelines(line)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `seek()` method as mentioned in the other answer to get exactly one line at a time, edit it and write it back. You still need to be cautious of the mode though.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, "r+") as file:
    for i, row in enumerate(file):
        if <your test>:
            # your update function
            row = update(row)
            file.seek(i * (len(row)+1))
            file.write(row)
            break
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**