# How to edit a line of a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, txt

I have a `txt` file that looks like this:

```
112
```

I just want to add `1` to that line using a Python command. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

This feels too much like a learning / homework effort, so let's not ruin that for you:

1. You read all lines *before* the line you want to edit, and write them to a temporary output file
2. you read the line, append your 1, and write it to your temporary output file
3. You read all lines *after* the line you want to edit, and write them to a temporary output file
4. You close the input file, unlink/delete it and rename the temporary file so that it replaces the original file.

You can alternatively edit the file in-place, but it will require you to first read all the lines *after* the line you want to edit into a temporary buffer, then modify the line, then overwrite everything after the modified positions back.

Files have no notion of "lines". They deal in bytes. If you need to insert a byte somewhere in the file, you need to move everything after that byte's position backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file, replace the line and rewrite the file domething like :

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
 
filedata = filedata.replace('112', '1112')
 
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

if you want add 1 to all line you can use something to modify all lines like:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

list_num = []
for num in  filedata.split('\n')[:-1]:
    list_num.append(str(int(num)+1))

'\n'.join(list_num)
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write('\n'.join(list_num) + '\n')
```